# How to swap digits in number?

Tags: java

I need to write function that gets 3 params(int num, int k, int nDigit).
The function get number and replace the digit inside the number in k index by nDigit.

for example:

```
 int num  = 5498
 int k  = 2
 int nDigit= 3

the result is num = 5398
```

My question is how can I implement it?I undastand that the best way to convert the num to string and then just replace char on specific index by nDigit char.

But is there any way to implement it?Without

Comment: Where's your code? What's the problem with the approach you're suggesting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't do your homework for you, but here's some hints:

Convert integer to string:

```
String s = Integer.toString(1234);
```

Enumerating a string:

```
 for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
 {
     char c = s.charAt(i);
 }
```

String building (a little less efficient without the StringBuilder class)

```
 char c = '1';
 String s = "3";

 String j = "";
 j = j + c;
 j = j + s;   // j is now equal to "13"
```

String back to integer:

```
 int val = Integer.parseInt("42");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public int changeDigit(int num, int k, int nDigit){
    k = pow(10,k);
    double saved = num%k; // Save digits after
    num = num - (num%(k*10)); //Get what's before k
    return ((int) (num + (nDigit*k) + saved));
}
```

Comment: You're probably just doing a student's homework for him.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `StringBuilder`. It's easier to see what you're doing and you don't need to perform mathematics, only adjust the characters in their positions. Then convert it back to `int`.

```
public class Main {
    static int swapParams(int num, int k, int nDigit) {
        StringBuilder myName = new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(num));
        myName.setCharAt(k-1, Integer.toString(nDigit).charAt(0));
        return Integer.parseInt(myName.toString());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(swapParams(5498, 2, 3));
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/e4MF6m

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
public int func(int num, int k, int nDigit) {
    String number = String.valueOf(num);
    return Integer.parseInt(number.substring(0, k - 1) + nDigit + number.substring(k, number.length()));

}
```

This function takes the first characters of the number without the k'th number and adds the nDigit to it. Then it adds the last part of the number and returns it as an integer number.

Answer (score 1):

This is my javascript solution.

```
 const solution = numbers => {   //declare a variable that will hold
the array el that is not strictly ascending   let flawedIndex;
      //declare a boolean variable to actually check if there is a flawed array el in the given array   let flawed = false;
      //iterate through the given array   for(let i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
     
     //check if current array el is greater than the next
     if(numbers[i] > numbers[i+1])
       {
         //check if we already set flawed to true once.
         //if flawed==true, then return that this array cannot be sorted
         //strictly ascending even if we swap one elements digits
         
         if(flawed) {
           
           return false;
         }
         
         //if flawed is false, then set it to true and store the index of the flawed array el
         else {
           
                            flawed = true;
                        flawedIndex = i;
                                }
       }
        }
      //if flawed is still false after the end of the for loop, return true    //where true = the array is sctrictly ascending   if(flawed ==
 false) return true;
      //if flawed==true, that is there is an array el that is flawed   if(flawed){
 
     //store the result of calling the swap function on the digits of the flawed array el
     let swapResult = swap(flawedIndex,numbers);
 
     //if the swapresult is true, then return that it is ascending
     if (swapResult == true) return true;   }
      //else return that its false   return false; }
 
 const swap = (flawIndex, numbers) => {
      let num = numbers[flawIndex];
      //convert the given array el to a string, and split the string based on ''   let numToString = num.toString().split('');
 
 //iterate through every digit from index 0   for(let i=0;
 i<numToString.length; i++) { 
   
     //iterate from every digit from index 1
     for(let j=i+1; j<numToString.length; j++) { 
     
       //swap the first index digit with every other index digit 
       let temp = numToString[i];
       numToString[i] = numToString[j]
       numToString[j] = temp;
       
       console.log(numToString)
       
       //check if the swapped number is lesser than the next number in the main array
       //AND if it is greater than the previous el in the array. if yes, return true
       let swappedNum = Number(numToString.join(''));
       if(swappedNum < numbers[flawIndex + 1] && swappedNum > numbers[flawIndex-]) 
   {
         return true;
       }
         
     }   }   //else return false   return false; }
```

> console.log("the solution is ",solution([1, 3, 900, 10]))